# The process cannot access file being use by another process

Tags: c#, asp.net

when i create web form under new project in visual studio 12 error have  show the process is  cannot access the file 
`C:\Users\mayur\AppData\Local\Temp\hhdfvogm.yzm` (my system local path show) because  of it being use by another process 
how to solve these error please

Comment: Try to close Visual Studio and delete that file.

Comment: yes i do these process but error are show even i have also uninstalled visual studio and again installed visual studio 2 or 3 work properly after that  show again these error

Comment: Do you use IIS on the same machine? May be IIS is using that file and you need to stop IIS at that moment?

Comment: yes i use please tell me process how to stop IIS

Comment: By rebooting. If the file is locked after that, maybe there is a virus scanner/backup software or something similar at work.

Comment: Push Windows+R write inetmgr and look this screenshot http://take.ms/oDhus

Comment: You could try using [process explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) to see what is using that file.

Comment: Generally this kind of error occurred because of Antivirus programmers, that may be using same file as your are trying to access. to solve this issue you could stop your antivirus service and try again to run the application.

Comment: @VDWWD no sir its not solution

Comment: Then Visual Studio is not the problem here.

Comment: first of thanks all guys  @ jaydeip i have tried your solution, its work when i am save project another drive then the webfrom had been create, when went to save thise project on c drive the webform will not created show same above error,